# How can mechanical energy be preserved if the potential energy is negative?

Tags: classical-mechanics, reference-frames, energy-conservation, potential-energy

If I set the upwards direction as positive, the gravitational acceleration $g$ will be negative (and thus, $mgh$ will be negative if $h$ is positive). Thus, the potential energy will be negative, but the kinetic energy cannot be negative. Thusly, as the absolute value of the potential energy decreases and the value of the kinetic energy increases, it is impossible for their sum to remain the same. From one endpoint to another, the sum will go from negative to positive.

All of this would be solved if one wrote that the preservation of mechanical energy entailed $E_m = |E_p| + E_k$. Perhaps this is the correct formulation, and my textbook is inaccurate?

Comment: As a reminder, in this context the symbol $g$ is shorthand for $9.8$ m/s$^2$, and is positive regardless of how you choose your coordinates. If you choose your coordinates such that "up" is the positive $y$-direction, then the gravitational acceleration is $\mathbf a_g = - g \hat y$. Under **no** circumstances should the $g$ which appears in e.g. $PE = mgy$ or ($mgh$, or whatever convention you use) be taken to be negative.

Comment: Can you maybe clarify?  It's entirely unclear from your post *why* or *how* you think that the sum will go from negative to positive (or even change at all). Without that, it's difficult to answer your question because we can't see where the error in reasoning is. In any case, you should *not* take the absolute value of the potential energy.

Comment: @J.Murray If that's the case, you have the answer to my question.

Comment: @march See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

> Thus, the potential energy will be negative, but the kinetic energy
> cannot be negative.

The potential energy will be negative *relative to a point an infinite distance away from the Earth* where the potential energy is considered zero. This follows from the general form of the equation for the gravitational potential energy $U$ of an object of mass $m$ due to the attraction of a mass $M$, where $G$ is the universal gravitation constant, and potential energy is assigned a value of zero at $r$ equal to infinity.

$$U=-\frac {GMm}{r}$$

From this equation we see that the gravitational potential energy of $m$  becomes increasingly negative as $m$ nears $M$ and has some negative value at the surface of the Earth. Conversely, when one moves away from the surface of the Earth $U$ becomes less negative, which is the same as saying the potential energy increases as you move away from the Earth. Thus, at a height $h$ near the surface of the where the acceleration due to gravity can be considered constant at $g$, the potential energy *relative to the surface of the Earth* is positive and is given as

$$U=mgh$$

If the object is released at rest from height $h$ its potential energy decreases while its kinetic energy correspondently increases so that (in the absence of air resistance) mechanical energy is conserved, or

$$\Delta PE +\Delta KE =0$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The potential energy change accompanying a displacement $\Delta \vec x$ of mass $m$ is $-m\vec g\cdot\Delta \vec x$. If you define the potential energy to be zero on the "ground", this makes potential energy positive above the ground, however you choose your axes. Potential energy could be negative, depending on what arbitrary potential you assign to "ground".

The usual potential energy expression "$mgh$" takes $g$ to be the magnitude of gravitational acceleration, i.e. a positive number. $E_m = E_p + E_k$ is conserved for a system on which no work is being done, and your proposed mechanical energy isn't, unless potential energy is always positive for a particular system.

Answer (score 0):

> If I set the upwards direction as positive, the gravitational
> acceleration $g$ will be negative and thus, $m\,g\,h$ will be negative
> if $h$ is positive.

**$\hat u$ is a unit vector pointing upwards.**
$\vec g = g (-\hat u) = -g\,\hat u$
$\vec h = h\,\hat u$
Work done by an upward **external** force $m\,g\,\hat u$ in moving mass $m$ an upward displacement  $h\,\hat u$ is $(m\,g\,\hat u) \cdot (h\,\hat u) = m\,g\,h$ and this is the **change** in the gravitational potential energy of the mass (and Earth) system.

The choice of positive direction does not affect the the value of the change in potential energy.

**$\hat d$ is a unit vector pointing downwards.**
$\vec g = g \,\hat d$
$\vec h = h (-\hat d) = -h\,\hat u$
Work done by an upward **external** force $m\,g(-\hat d)$ in moving mass $m$ an upward displacement  $-h\,\hat u$ is $(-m\,g\,\hat d) \cdot (-h\,\hat u) = m\,g\,h$ and this is the change in the gravitational potential energy of the mass (and Earth) system.

The mass is thrown upwards a vertical distance $h$.
There is an increase in the gravitational potential energy $m\,g\,h$ and an equal decrease in the kinetic energy of the mass $\frac 12 m\,v^2_{\rm final} - \frac 12 m\,v^2_{\rm initial}$.

Notice that I have referred to the **change** in the gravitational potential energy.
In this example the change is positive and the size of the change does not depend on where the zero of gravitational potential energy is chose.
Thus the change in gravitational potential energy could be from from $90\,\rm J$ to $100\,\rm J$, or $0\,\rm J$ to $10\,\rm J$, or from $-5\,\rm J$ to $5\,\rm J$, or from $-10\,\rm J$ to $0\,\rm J$, or from $-100\,\rm J$ to $-90\,\rm J$ etc, with all changes being $10
\,\rm J$.